# Are two children from different mothers but the same gentile father considered sibilings?

Tags: halacha, family-members, arayot, intermarriage

Two children that have the same father but different mothers are forbidden to have relations on grounds of incest. If their father is a gentile (and they have different Jewish mothers), it is not really their father, therefore are they still forbidden to have relations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was raised by the Assia journal conjunction with artificial fertilization.

It is a problem to take sperm from another Jew because the child could marry his brother. It may be permitted to take sperm of a non-Jew in this case because they are not considered to be brothers.

> , שהטעם "עיקרי לאיסור הזרעה מיהודי זר לאשת-איש - "שמא ישא אחותו
>   מאביו" - לא קיים במקרה שהזרע הוא של גוי. זאת מכיון שאין הולד מתייחס
>   אחר אב-גוי גם כשהוא נולד כדרך כל הארץ, לא כל שכן בצורת הזרעה מלאכותית.‏

```
http://98.131.138.124/articles/assia/assia1/r001128.asp
```

( *for some reason the link doesn't work as a link; if you'd like to see the article you can copy-paste the link from here* )